# The sum of the harmonic series and the negative harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I haven't been able to find an answer to this on here or elsewhere, so I apologize if I missed it.

Here's what I know:

1. The harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ diverges.
2. The negative harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac1n$ diverges.
3. The terms $\frac1n$ and $-\frac1n$ cancel each other out for all n.
4. The sum of two divergent series is divergent.

So the question is: what is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ + $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac1n$? 0 or divergent?

If divergent is the answer, I am curious if there is any more reason other than definition.

If the answer is convergent to 0, I am curious on a more detailed answer other than simply "the terms cancel out".

Additionally, we can extend this question to integrals as well:
Does $\int_1^\infty\frac1x$ + $\int_1^\infty-\frac1x$ = 0 or is it divergent?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Neither zero nor divergent; it's non-existent. $\sum(1/n)$ is not a number, $\sum(-1/n)$ is not a number, and you can't add two things unless they are both numbers (or elements of some more general algebraic structure where addition is defined).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely divergent.

"$\infty -\infty$" has no sence even in extended real number system.